# Rest Service and Zip could search

Tags: java, rest

Hi I am trying to do a program on net beans using java and I have to Write a REST service that takes zip code and return the state. The REST service should provide path and query parameters. what is wrong with the code?

```
   public class Users {

   private String userId;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String State; 
  private int Zipcode;

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setState(String State) {
        this.State = State;
    }

    public void setZipcode(int Zipcode) {
        this.Zipcode = Zipcode;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public int getZipcode() {
        return Zipcode;
    }

@Get
@Path("Zipcode")
public String getZipcode (@QueryParam("Zipcode") String Zipcode, @QueryParam("State") String State) {
loadUser();
for (Users u : users) { 
if(getZipcode => 77002 && <= 77099);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, State);

else if (getZipcode => 77449 && <= 77494);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, State);

else if (getZipcode => 77502 && <= 77506); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, State);

else if (getZipcode => 77550 && <= 77555); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, State);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Zipcode is invaild, please try again" );
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong ? You should probably explain this also

Comment: I cant find anything wrong with it. there was no errors in the User class. the else if statements keep coming up as a error. I checked the else if statement and it looks correct to me.

Comment: Superior or equal is written >= in java. Also the && operator is used between two expressions: getZipCode >= 77550 is a valid expression, but "<=77555" is not.

Comment: Also there is generally no semicolon after an if statement. You should get a good book or tutorial about Java basics, you have not understood the syntax well yet.

Comment: Thanks. I always miss the little details, trying to get extra help with programming.